# How to clone a user's settings

Tags: gnome, 16.04, administration

I have to set up a bunch of computers and a bunch of user accounts to set up on **Ubuntu Gnome**.

I'd like to set up a standard 'skel'eton as a base for new accounts. Here's what I've done so far.

1. Created a `skel` user and set up the desktop as I want it.
2. Copy the `/home/skel` files to `/etc/skel`
3. Dump the dconf settings for this user

   ```
   dconf dump / >skel_settings
   ```
4. Add user `adduser test1`
5. Login as `test1` and re-import the settings

   ```
   dconf load / <skel_settings
   ```

But this *still* misses some details, e.g. shell extensions are missing and the default applications for opening Directories is wrong.

Is there a better/fuller way?

### EDIT

actually, I think this works! Think I did something wrong with rsync...

Comment: In the home folder there are many hidden folders with settings. In Nautilus, press CTRL+H to see them. They all start with periods, making them hidden.

Comment: Thanks Dorian. Yes I'm aware of hidden files and I made sure I copied them to the `/etc/skel` folder :-)

Comment: All applications _should_ save their settings in the home folder, or dconf, but there are some system applications and daemons that may store settings in the /etc folder as well.

Comment: I see your edit... are you all set now, or do you still need any help?

Comment: Think I'm all set, think I might change q and put the 2nd half in as an answer - useful resource for others?

Comment: I think manually dumping and importing `dconf` settings is superfluous as the `dconf` database is already stored in every user's home directory (`~/.config/dconf/*`)

Comment: yeah, you might be right about that.