# How to have gnome-tweak-tool settings the same for all users

Tags: gnome, dconf, gsettings, gnome-tweak-tool

I want to migrate the gnome-tweak-tool settings to `/etc/skel` so that all users can get the same gnome3 look and extensions.

I copied all my extensions folder `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` to `/etc/skel`. But they do not get enabled by default for new users. So I am guessing dconf settings (or gnome-tweak-tool settings) also need to be copied and enabled for the new user.

I can back up my dconf using 
`dconf dump / > some_file`

I found that [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795189/how-to-clone-a-users-settings)

How do I import dconf and shell extensions at gnome3 session login and preferably through `/etc/skel`?

Answer (score 3):

This [guide](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/extensions-enable.html.en) helped me.

To make extensions available to all users on the system, install them in the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` directory.

> Note that newly-installed machine-wide extensions are disabled by default.

To enable the extensions for all users, you need to set the `org.gnome.shell.enabled-extensions` key. To set it, create a user profile in `/etc/dconf/profile/user`:

```
user-db:user
system-db:local
```

Create a local database for machine-wide settings in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-extensions`. Note that the directory does not exist on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
[org/gnome/shell]
# List all extensions that you want to have enabled for all users
enabled-extensions=['myextension1@myname.example.com', 'myextension2@myname.example.com']
```

The enabled-extensions key specifies the enabled extensions using the extension's uuid (myextension1@myname.example.com and myextension2@myname.example.com).

To complete it, update the system databases with:

```
dconf update
```